# Vega heat map over geographic map

Tags: javascript, gis, heatmap, vega

Does anyone have an example of how I could achieve plotting a heat map over a geographic map using Vega? I realize the Vega heat map is more intended for comparing `X` vs `Y` values and not actually geography, but it would be really helpful to be able achieve that feature.:

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/county-unemployment/

https://vega.github.io/vega/examples/heatmap/

Has anyone had success doing something like this? One solution could be that I overlap a second geographic map in a grid pattern and color each cell in that map according to some algorithm I write, but I'd prefer to use an external library than replicate pre-existing functionality. If there is another library I should be using instead, that would work just as well.

Comment: Can be done with leaflet.js. See http://leafletjs.com/examples/choropleth/